# cloud storageでのリージョン選択とテーブルのリジョンが一致しない

Tags: database, google-cloud

お世話になっております。

Google cloudでAI株価予測をできるようにすることがゴールです。その設定の過程のリージョン選択がうまくいかない状態です。具体的には、cloud storage内のリージョンを選択欄について、選択欄がMulti-region、Dual-region、Regionの3つです。今回は、Multi-regionを選択し、US（米国の複数のリージョン）を選択しております。

次に、テーブルの設定についてです。こちら、リージョン選択がグローバルと欧州連合の2種類の選択肢のみになります。米国がなく、グローバルを選択し、Cloud Storage から CSV ファイルを選択しようとしたところ、「インスタンスと同じリージョン内に存在する必要があります。」というエラーメッセージが出てしまいます。

本件、上記のエラーメッセージの解消方法のご教授をお願いできればと思います。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: Cloud Storageのリージョンを `us-central1` で作成し直して、それを指定してみてはいかがでしょうか？

Comment: ありがとうございます！！　こちらで一度試させていただきます！！